# Counting bigrams (pair of two characters) in a file

Tags: c, counter

I want to count the number of occurrences of all bigrams (pair of characters) in a file using C language. Bigram counts count the frequency of pairs of characters. Actually this is about Letter Frequencies. i implemented monogram but i didn't find a solution related to bigrams.

Here is my code and this is monogram counting, how can i change this if statement? This code just count one word. For example i want to count "ac, dh, tx.. etc." characters. i prepared a txt file 2-gram frequencies as a list and read from this file. (ar, la, an... etc.) by this means: `FILE *plain = fopen("bigram.txt", "r");`but how can i design the code counting multiple characters in a file? Thank you so much.

```
int main(){

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
    char string[9000];
    int c = 0, count[30] = {0};
    int bahar = 0;    

    ...
        if ( string[c] >= 'a' && string[c] <= 'z' ){
            count[string[c]-'a']++;
            bahar++;

}
```

Comment: Well, how do you access the character after `string[c]`? Once you know that surely you can work out how to check two adjacent characters? And what does your question have to do with `r`? Please use only the relevant tags.

Comment: perhaps instead of using a one dimensional array count[30], you could use a two dimensional array count[26][26], and have it indexed by each of two consecutive characters in string. For example, `count[string[c]][string[c+1]]++`

Comment: Do you count bigrams across word boundaries?  That is, given "ant farm" as input, is `tf` one of the bigrams to be counted?  Presumably, you're not concerned about the case of the letters in English.  You set locale to `en_US.UTF-8`; does that mean you want to count accented characters too?  Are `à`, `á`, `æ`, `ä`, `å`, `â`, `ã`, all equivalent to `a`?  If you need to read UTF-8 characters, you have to work a bit harder, and recognizing the equivalence of accented variants of `a` is decidedly more complex.

Comment: @user3121023 of course, `hiç uyuyamam cümlesi artık tarihe karışmıştır o kadar saat uyumadan durmanın da bir faydası yoktur uçtuğunuz yöne ve süreye bağlı olarak yaşayacağınız jetlaglerin etkisini en aza indirme yolu da iyi bir hesaplama ile ne kadar uyuyacağını bilmekten geçer ikinci bir derinlemesine tahlili kaldıramayacağınızı düşündüğümden bu önemli noktayı gelecek ayki yazıya bırakıyorum yolunuz uzun olsa da açık olsun koltuğunuz dar olsa da rahat olsun çç çç çç çç aç çç aç aç aç aç xç`

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this problem easily with a single loop:

- using a 2D array `count[26][26]` initialized to `0`.
- read bytes from the file one at a time
- if the byte is a lowercase letter and the last byte was too, increment the corresponding counter.
- loop until end of file.
- print the stats.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int count['z' - 'a' + 1]['z' - 'a' + 1] = {{ 0 }};
    int c0 = EOF, c1;
    FILE *plain = fopen("bigram.txt", "r");

    if (plain != NULL) {
        while ((c1 = getc(plain)) != EOF) {
            if (c1 >= 'a' && c1 <= 'z' && c0 >= 'a' && c0 <= 'z') {
                count[c0 - 'a'][c1 - 'a']++;
            }
            c0 = c1;
        }
        fclose(plain);
        for (c0 = 'a'; c0 <= 'z'; c0++) {
            for (c1 = 'a'; c1 <= 'z'; c1++) {
                int n = count[c0 - 'a'][c1 - 'a'];
                if (n) {
                    printf("%c%c: %d\n", c0, c1, n);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a more general version that can handle any 8-bit character pairs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    /* character set: must use single byte encoding */
    /* the last 5 bytes correspond to ışçöü in ISO-8859-9 */
    const char set[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\xFD\xFxE7\xF6\xFC";
    const int setlen = (sizeof(set) - 1);
    int count[setlen][setlen];
    char *p0 = NULL;
    int c1;
    FILE *plain = fopen("bigram.txt", "r");

    memset(count, 0, sizeof(count));

    if (plain != NULL) {
        while ((c1 = getc(plain)) != EOF) {
            char *p1 = memchr(set, c1, setlen);
            if (p1 != NULL && p0 != NULL) {
                count[p0 - set][p1 - set]++;
            }
            p0 = p1;
        }
        fclose(plain);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < setlen; i++) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < setlen; j++) {
                int n = count[i][j];
                if (n > 0) {
                    printf("%c%c: %d\n", set[i], set[j], n);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i need some turkish characters this is why i added this lines inside if statement: `else if (c1 == 0xE7 && c0 == 0xE7){ //ç count[c0-0xE7][c1-0xE7]++; }` and this lines: `int n =  count[c0-0xE7][c1-0xE7]; if (n) { printf("%c%c: %d\n", c0, c1, n); }` but doesn't work it. how can i change? Thank you so much.

Comment: If you want to handle non-ASCII characters too, it becomes much more tricky. You must handle the encoding and determine which characters you want to track. You seem to use the UTF-8 encoding: non-ASCII characters are encoded as multiple bytes, you would need to parse the string or the stream to get the code point values but be aware that not all Turkish characters lay below 256. `Ğ` is `\u011E`, `ğ` is `\u011F`, `İ` is `\u0130`, `ı` `\u0131`, `Ş` `\u015E` and `ş` `\u015F`.

Comment: first i changed this line: `int count[32][32] = {{ 0 }};` and how can i add if statement this characters,  i tried this way doesnt work it : `else if (c1 == 0xE7 && c0 == 0xE7){ //ç count[c0-0xE7][c1-0xE7]++; }` and printf doesn't work it, either. ı,ş,ç,ö and ü. Just i have to add 5 characters.

Comment: @jekyll: I shall update the code with a quick fix as long as you use ISO-8859-9, the byte oriented character encoding for Turkish. see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-9

Comment: Note: In C this is not mandatory that 'a', 'b', etc. are consecutive (Of course in practice it's work, 99% of the time). Tipo: `int count[setlen][lenlen];` => `int count[setlen][setlen];`?

Comment: i changed this line yes: `int count[setlen][lenlen]; => int count[setlen][setlen];` but this characters \xFD\xFxE7\xF6\xFC still doesnt counting in my plaintext i will changed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-9 @chqrlie Thank you and happy new year.

Comment: `\u00E7\u00F6\u00FC\u011F\u0131` doesnt work either. i tried everything my output is `\261\304: 6` this is wrong octal characters. Or this one : `ğ: 41 ı: 213` not even pair. This Turkish characters is really the very devil. @chqrlie

Comment: @Stargateur: indeed letters are not consecutive in EBCDIC, but `'a'` is the smallest and `'z'` the largest, hence my array definition `int count['z' - 'a' + 1]['z' - 'a' + 1]`. Alas even this is not guaranteed by the standard.  My second proposal is more general and makes no assumptions about the particular order and values for the target characters. Typo fixed too. Thank you.

Comment: @chqrlie your code is perfect, thank you so much. i will solve this TR characters. Thank you again.

Comment: @jekyll: you can accept this or another answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.